# Android's CalendarView widget for lower API

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm creating a game, which shows a Calendar and a question: when is it Christmas? If you press on December 25th it appears a toast saying "Congratulations". It is a wonderful game, and it works perfectly.
I'm using CalendarView widget, which works well for API level 24.

```
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener;
```

The problem is when trying to use a lower version of Android. Then, when I call the initializeCalendar() function, appears the error:

> Call requires API level 24 (current min is 19)

What alternative do I have? I need to use API 19. 
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I do not see an `initializeCalendar()` method [on `CalendarView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare, you are right!! Sorry!! It was a function a copied from a tutorial! I deleted a line and now the problem is Simple DateFormat (Call requires API level 24 (current min is 19): new android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat) I will work on this error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The function initializeCalendar() was this:

> public void initializeCalendar() {
>           calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.simpleCalendarView);

```
    // sets the first day of week according to Calendar.
    // here we set Monday as the first day of the Calendar
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(2);
    String string_date = "1-8-2017";
    long milliseconds = 0;

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    try {
        Date d = f.parse(string_date);
        milliseconds = d.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
```

And there were the problem. Thank you, @CommonsWare, who commented.

Comment: done. I was importing a incorrect class for SimpleDateFormat. The right one was java.text.SimpleDateFormat.